# Reliable Wikimedia Commons uploader

Tags: linux, mediawiki, wikimedia-commons, uploader

When uploading pictures to Wikimedia Commons, I usually use the [online Upload Wizard](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:UploadWizard), but it has several problems:

- You have to select files using your browser's file selection dialog, which is very brittle. You have to hold CTRL when clicking, and if you forget you loose the whole selection.
- It often fails without giving any reason, then you have to re-select and re-categorize and re-enter descriptions, which can take hours.

I am looking for a much more reliable uploader:

- Convenient selection
- Category auto-completion & suggestions (near-looking names even if typed part has a typo)
- Ability to copy entered metadata of a particular to all files below it
- Remembers metadata your entered, even after failure to upload
- Explains each failed upload
- Lets you fix and retry failed uploads
- Suggest categories based on EXIF latitude/longitude
- Works on Ubuntu

Comment: I guess you have taken a look at https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons:Upload_tools and https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons:Batch_uploading

Comment: @SVilcans: I am currently investigating them. I don't have enough experience with them to post any answer here though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [VicuñaUploader](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons:Vicu%C3%B1aUploader) regularly, and it has most of the features you required except two:

[image]

- YES: Convenient selection
- HALF (auto-completion but typos not allowed): Category auto-completion & suggestions (near-looking names even if typed part has a typo)
- YES: Ability to copy entered metadata of a particular to all files below it
- YES: Remembers metadata your entered, even after failure to upload
- YES: Explains each failed upload
- YES: Lets you fix and retry failed uploads
- NO: Suggest categories based on EXIF latitude/longitude
- YES: Works on Ubuntu

Comment: It would be useful to understand why people are downvoting this. Thousands of happy users uploaded oer a million files with this tool: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Uploaded_with_Vicu%C3%B1aUploader